# PHP session in multi thread share delay

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I use Ubuntu,Apache 2 and PHP 5.5. I have a question: If I use multi work to run apache, these threads will share php session? or have some delay?

Because I use Laravel(session default) write a competition website, and I use session to store project id for facebook callback use:

Vote(store projectid in session) -> get facebook login url -> login -> callback(get projectid)

If I click "Vote" fast, sometime callback function can't get session.

currently I use other way send projectid to callback, but I want know why happen this thing, thanks :)